# What's a better word for sole in this expression?

Tags: adjectives

I want to say 'in comparison to merely increasing of X,...'

what would be a better word for sole here? (It should be formal, I'm writing it in my paper)

**compared to sole increase of X,...**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One might say "instead of just increasing X," This means that only X will be increased to give the result.  You could also say "compared to just increasing X," with the same meaning.

Comment: Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 1):

"Compared to an independent increase in x" allows you to keep the sentence order and means only x increased. The problem is that this also says the increase in x *did not depend on another factor*. If you want to replace 'sole' but don't want to make a comment about it depending on something, you can replace independent with "exclusive."

Comment: Thank you for responding.

Comment: Any time. I hope it helped.